# Overwritten object/data type Range

Tags: excel, vba

I was writing a function in VBA, and when I was writing the input variables I accidentally wrote "range as Range" and now the actual data type Range is overwritten in excel it seems, no matter what file I open.

So now, if I write "x as Range" it doesn't make the Range in blue as it does for instance if I would classify it as Integer instead. So now none of my macros or functions that use the Range data type in the code work.

Is there a way to reset or remove this?

Comment: Rename the variable (though it shouldn't affect other workbooks even if the declaration were public)

Comment: Try a one-line sub including ***Set Range = Nothing***

Comment: It is possible (though not very wise) to declare a variable or parameter with name `range` - no problem. The only thing that will break your code is to declare a user type named  `range` or a module or class module named `range`.

Comment: @FunThomas depending on scope, it could affect any calls to the `Range` property.

Comment: @Rory: You have any examples? In the tests I did, VBA could clearly distinguish between a variable named `range` and the data type.

Comment: @FunThomas Make a module level declaration, then in a routine in the same module, try and assign a range to a variable using something like `Set rg = Range("A1")` and you'd get an object error, since it thinks `Range` is the variable, not the property.

Comment: Not really sure what happened or what solved it, but it is back to normal now fortunately. Thank you all for the help!